# Tensorflow Lite: error on AllocateTensors() when I make .tflite using flatc

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to test my model using tensorflow-lite on x86_64 PC.

I coded a c++ test code and succeed interpreting given mobilenet model and executing inference. 
I wanted to change some operation in the model to my custom operation. 
Before doing that, I checked whether I can convert .tflite to json correctly.
What I did is changing the mobilenet.lite to mobilenet.json using flatc and tensorflow lite's schema (schema.fbs) and re-changing the mobilenet.json to mobilenet_new.lite.
However, when I tested mobilenet_new.lite, error occurs like below :  tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/kernel_util.cc:35 std::abs(input_product_scale - bias_scale) <= 1e-6 * std::min(input_product_scale, bias_scale) was not true.

When I converted the mobilenet_new.lite to mobilenet_new.json, two JSON files were the same without any difference. Why does this error happen? If the parameter values are the same, how this can be possible?

If you have knowledge about this, please give me help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on the changes you made to the model? Also, in case you haven't seen this already, here's a reference on extending TFLite with custom operations : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/custom_operators.md

Answer (score 0):

I has resolved this.

when I debug this problem, it was flatbuffer problem.
flatbuffer change float to string when make json file.
So, it becomes fixed point value with precision 6. This makes float value rounding.
So, when I converted tflite -> json -> tflite, there was some change between two tflite files.